# New to Python im scraping a website but I think there is an issue with the html tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup

I was able to successfully scrape this website but it is not working correctly. This is the output I'm getting which is the empty dictionary. Would really appreciate if someone could confirm if its the HTML tags or deny specify. I've include an image of the terminal output here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWLYk.png)
The desired behavior is I want to store the send a URL request to the website, then target the table which includes all asset information and scrape the names and tickers for the assets, then finally store them in a .csv file.

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import pandas as pd
##import urllib.parse

API_KEY = '7bbcbb39-029f-4075-97bc-6b57b6e9e68b'

def get_scrapeops_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://proxy.scrapeops.io/v1/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

r = requests.get(get_scrapeops_url('https://bitbox.swiss/coins/'))
response = r.text


#r = requests.get('https://bitbox.swiss/coins/')

#list to store scraped data
data = []

#

soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
result = soup.find('div',class_ = 'coins-table')

# parse through the website's html
name = soup.find('strong',style = 'cursor: auto;')
ticker = soup.find('span',style = 'cursor: auto;')

#Store data in a dictionary using key value pairs
d = {'name':name.text if name else None,'ticker':ticker.text if ticker else None} 

data.append(d)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_df.to_csv("coins_scrape.csv", index=False)

print(data_df)
```

'''

Comment: There are no <span> or <strong> elements with the specified style in that HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coin names are loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can use `requests` module to simulate it:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://bitbox.swiss/coins/tokens.json'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                      address                                    name         unit
0    e41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498                             0x Protocol          ZRX
1    b6ed7644c69416d67b522e20bc294a9a9b405b31                               0xBitcoin        0xBTC
2    111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302                           1inch Network        1INCH
3    a4ef4b0b23c1fc81d3f9ecf93510e64f58a4a016                            1MillionNFTs         1MIL
4    2c9c19ce3b15ae77c6d80aec3c1194cfd6f7f3fa                               2crazyNFT         2CRZ
5    ff44b5719f0b77a9951636fc5e69d3a1fc9e7d73                               4ART Coin         4ART
6    8888801af4d980682e47f1a9036e589479e835c5                                   88mph          MPH
7    feea0bdd3d07eb6fe305938878c0cadbfa169042                                    8PAY         8PAY
8    7fc66500c84a76ad7e9c93437bfc5ac33e2ddae9                                    Aave         AAVE

...
```

Comment: Ah, i see! you got the json data from the https://bitbox.swiss/coins/tokens.json in your code. Would you mind breaking down what each line is doing? I would like to understand this further thank you!!

Comment: how did you figure out that the data was being loaded from an external URL?

Comment: how did you figure out that the data was being loaded from an external URL?

could you also explain the below line of code
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'}

Comment: @Zer0chance_ When I observed the source code of the HTML page (`Ctrl + U`) I noticed, the data from the table isn't there, so the page must get them somewhere else. When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and reload the page you will see this URL with data there. The `headers` are needed by the server (otherwise it doesn't send any data)

Comment: got it! and im assuming this is the sever correct?

{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'}

Comment: @Zer0chance_ No, this is the User Agent the browser (or in this case `requests`) sends to the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent